# Lebesgue Measure of $A=\left \{ (x,0) : x \in [0,1]\right \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A=\left \{ (x,0) : x \in [0,1]\right \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $m_2$ Lebesgue Measure of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to determine $m_2(A)$. So. I know that Lebesgue Measure of interval is b-a. And in my case $(b_1-a_1)(b_2-a_2)=(1-0)*0=0$. But how can I show this by definition?

Comment: Try rewriting your set as a cartesian product of an interval and $\{0\}$. Then you can show this straight from the definition.

Comment: Is this correct: $m_2([0,1]\times {0})=inf \left \{ l([0,1]\times \left \{0 \right \}) : A \subset [0,1]\times {0}\right \} =0$

Answer (score 2):

The formula $m^*(A \times B) \leq m^*(A) m^*(B)$ is easy to prove in general, where $m^*$ is the outer measure.